# How to represent a mathematical domain in IR?

Tags: c++, math, mathematical-morphology

I would like to define an object representing a mathematical domain from a list of constraints, but I don't have a clear idea on how to do that.

For example, I start from IR and I have the following constraints :

- x > 0
- x is not in ]3,5]
- x is not in [7,12[

Then, my domain is ]0,3] U ]5,7[ U [12,+oo .

**How can I nicely store that in a C++ structure ?** Have you ever did that before ? Moreover, I want to be able to check easilly if the domain is empty.

Comment: Boost has an `interval` class that does this type of stuff [`boost::numeric::interval`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm)

Comment: I'm not sure boost::interval can solve this problem. I don't well know this lib, but it seems not able to store union of intervals, right ?

Comment: What about a sorted `vector<interval>`  + some logic to merge overlapping/consecutive intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question.**

Actually, I followed the idea of sbabbi using a list of intervals coming from `boost/numeric/interval`, representing the union of intervals.

Here is an example :

```
typedef boost::numeric::interval_lib::rounded_math<double> RoundedPolicy;
typedef boost::numeric::interval_lib::checking_base<double> CheckingPolicy;
typedef boost::numeric::interval_lib::policies<RoundedPolicy,CheckingPolicy> IntervalPolicies;
typedef boost::numeric::interval<double,IntervalPolicies> interval;

//...

bool is_interval_empty(const interval& inter)
{
  return boost::numeric::empty(inter);
}

void restrict(interval& domain, const interval& inter)
{
  for(std::list<interval>::iterator it = domain.begin(); it != domain.end(); ++it)
    *it = boost::numeric::intersect(*it, inter);
  domain.remove_if(is_interval_empty);
}

void restrict(interval& domain, const interval& inter1, const interval& inter2)
{
  for(std::list<interval>::iterator it = domain.begin(); it != domain.end(); ++it)
  {
    domain.push_front(boost::numeric::intersect(*it, inter1));
    *it = boost::numeric::intersect(*it, inter2);
  }
  domain.remove_if(is_interval_empty);
}

//...

std::list<interval> domain;
for(unsigned long int i = 0; i < constraints.size(); ++i)
{
  if(constraints[i].is_lower_bound())
  {
    interval restriction(constraints[i].get_lower_bound(), std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity());
    restrict(domain, restriction);
  }
  else if(constraints[i].is_upper_bound())
  {
    interval restriction(-std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), constraints[i].get_upper_bound());
    restrict(domain, restriction);
  }
  else if(constraints[i].is_forbidden_range())
  {
    interval restriction1(-std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), constraints[i].get_lower_bound());
    interval restriction2(constraints[i].get_upper_bound(), std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity());
    restrict(domain, restriction1, restriction2);
  }
}

if(domain.size() == 0)
  std::cout << "empty domain" << std::endl;
else
  std::cout << "the domain exists" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to use "3rd party" tools like mentioned in the coments, you'll have to write your own Interval class. 
To do this, you can do something like this:

```
class Interval{
  struct Range{
     bool leftInclusive, rightInclusive;
     double left, right;
     bool operator<(Range other){return left<other.left;}
  }
  std::Set<Range> trueRanges;
  void addTrueRange(Range r){
    //check for overlaps
    //merge if overlapping
    //otherwise add to trueRanges
  }
  bool trueAt(double at){
   //find the range with the highest left-bound lower than at
   auto candidate = truethRanges.upper_bound(at); 

   if(candidate == trueRanged.end()) return false; // no range found

   //on-point checking here
   if(at <= candidate->left) return false;
   if(at >= candidate->right) return false;
   return true;
 }
}
```

The on-point checking is left out here because you cannot simply say `doubleOne == doubleTwo` because this mitght result in false negatives. So you have to say `ABS(doubleOne-doubleTwo) < tinyValue`.

For looking for overlaps you can have a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/lower_bound/).